# Handlebars / Dynamic index

Tags: dynamic, indexing, this, handlebars.js

I have a small issue on Handlebars that seems easy to solve but I can't...

I use the context:

```
{"ids":[1,2], "names":{"1":"dog", "2":"cat"}}
```

With the template:

```
{{#each ids}}
{{this}}: {{../names.[this]}}
{{/each}}
```

I got the error: **Invalid path: ...names.this**

How can I solve this issue?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an 'index' helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('index', function(o, p) {
    if (o && p) {
        return o[p];
    }
});
```

You would then write:

```
{{index ../names this}}
```